# Keras Conv3d layer not giving expected output

Tags: python, keras, artificial-intelligence, keras-layer

I have this model

```
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28), name=("Input")),
        keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation=("relu"), name=("ReLU")),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, name=("Dropout")),
        keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=("softmax"), name=("Softmax")),
        keras.layers.Conv3D(10, (10, 10, 10),name="Convolutional3D")
    ],
    name=("Model")
)
```

And use a model.fit to run it, whenever i run the code i get this error message
`ValueError: Input 0 of layer "Convolutional3D" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 10)`

Comment: What do you expect to happen by calling 3D convolution on a vector?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.